# Color and Colors class in Flutter

Tags: class, flutter, dart, colors, attributes

I was working with Colors class in Flutter.
Added a buildkey function with input "**Color** zinc" and the same takes the value like **Colors**.red, Colors purple etc.

However, if I add the input as "**Colors** Zinc" the values like **Colors**.red, Colors.purple throws an error. Why this is so?

The class **Colors** should match the input class (**Colors** in this case) I think?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JohS8.png)

Comment: Can you provide some error description? maybe screenshot of the error please?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could attach a screenshot or maybe paste the exact error that you are getting.

But meanwhile as I understood it, It seems like that you are telling this works fine for you:

```
Expanded buildkey(Color zinc, int buildnumber) { ... }
```

But you are getting some error with this:

```
Expanded buildkey(Colors zinc, int buildnumber) { ... }
```

Which is correct behaviour as Colors.[color] returns a swatch constant which is of type **color**.

e.g: `Color selection = Colors.green[400];`

For more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html

Comment: Yes exactly you got my question. I meant Colors.green is supposed to be an object of class Colors and not Color. So why during initializing we specify 'Color' and not 'Colors'.   I have also added the image with the question.

Comment: Okay, 'Colors' is a class that is not meant to be instantiated, instead you directly access its static and constant members, like this: Colors.green or Colors.white...
The variable at your end should be specifically of the type that matches this member variable's type and has nothing to do with the class.

Answer (score 0):

May be I found the solution of my issue..

When i looked into the dart file of colors class. I found that,
Colors.green is actually an object of Color class. Code is something like this

Class Colors

Color green = Color(....);

Might be that is the reason thats why it requires it requires color class while initilization of variable and not Colors.